# Compress last created folder with Compress-Archive

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pass folder path to Compress Archive function through clipboard but it shows me error.
I am using following code:

```
$toZipDirectory = 'C:\Users\sadam.shaikh\Desktop\Automate\'

$zipFilePath = 'C:\Users\sadam.shaikh\Desktop\Automate\zip.zip'

$Newness= Get-ChildItem -Path $toZipDirectory | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |

Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 | % { $_.FullName } | Clip

$directoryname= Get-Clipboard

Compress-Archive -Path $directoryname -DestinationPath $zipFilePath
```

*Error:
Compress-Archive : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument
that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:6 char:24
Compress-Archive -Path $directoryname -DestinationPath $zipFilePath
CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Compress-Archive], ParameterBindingValidationException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Compress-Archive*

Comment: why you dont do it: Compress-Archive -Path $toZipDirectory -DestinationPath $zipFilePath      ?

Comment: Because I want gci to search for last write folder and compress that one.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want zip the last created folder in $toZipDirectory:

```
$toZipDirectory = 'C:\Users\sadam.shaikh\Desktop\Automate'
$zipFilePath = 'C:\Users\sadam.shaikh\Desktop\Automate\zip.zip'

Get-ChildItem $toZipDirectory -directory | 
    sort CreationTime -Descending | select -First 1 | 
         Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $zipFilePath
```

Comment: I want to zip the last created folder in $toZipDirectory that is why I am using getchild by sorting. I need to make a dynamic process.

Comment: Then you shoud explain this into your ask... I have modified my answer